# NSData dataWithContentsOfFile returning null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to fetching a `JSON` file which exist in my `xcode` resources using this code

```
-(void)readJsonFiles
{
    NSString *str=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"classes.json"];
    NSLog(@"Path: %@", str);
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", fileData);
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithData:fileData];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);
}
```

path return me this link of file path

```
/Users/astutesol/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/A4E1145C-500C-4570-AF31-9E614FDEADE4/The Gym Factory.app/classes.json
```

but when I log `fileData` it return me `null` . I don't know where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Did you check whether your file exists at that path and what data it contains exactly?

Answer (score 31):

Instead of appending the path, use `pathForResource:ofType:`, so

```
NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"classes" ofType:@"json"];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
```

Comment: NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"classes" ofType:@"json"]; i tried this but it return null path on simulator

Comment: Are you sure your file has been copied to your application when it's compiled?

Comment: now i use geojson file within xcode and paste my json code inside this file it working now

Comment: Yeah probably your file earlier wasn't copied to your project which is why it kept returning `nil`. Glad it helped!

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer i have path, abd/abs/clasic.json then how can i can get "classic" so i can define in bundle?

Answer (score 6):

It's failed to read your file for some reason.  Use [-dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIDAAAF) to find out why.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str options: 0 error: &error];
if (fileData == nil)
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to read file, error %@", error);
}
else
{
    // parse the JSON etc
}
```

Comment: It is very important to detect the error and act in consequence. I used: NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; And when the picture is not loaded I did not know what to do. Again, it's very interesting your comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: i have path, abd/abs/clasic.json then how can i can get "classic" so i can define in bundle?

Answer (score 2):

There is the solution for Swift 3 :

```
//create a fil's path, decompose name and extension
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "anim-gif-1", ofType: "gif")
//get the data asociated to this file
let file = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

Comment: @Kavin i have path, abd/abs/clasic.json then how can i can get "classic" so i can define in bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pathforResource with resourcetype and check if there is data in your file.

That should not be nil.

Comment: this returning null to me 
 
NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"classes" ofType:@"json"]; i tried several technique but not working

Comment: Then check the name of your file which is in you mainbundle. If it is the same you have given or not.

Comment: dude name is same name is not the problem

Comment: Then try to alloc and init your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to get NSData from your document directory

```
NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

stringPath  = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JSON_FILE_NAME.json"];
NSLog(@"stringpath %@",stringPath);
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:stringPath];
```

Hope this will work for you.